# Hitting times and stopping times for cadlag processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $X$ be a cadlag stochastic process.  If $X$ is continuous, then I already know that

$\inf\{t\geq 0: X_t \in C\}$ is a stopping time whenever $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.  What if $X$ is only cadlag? (For every $\omega$)?

Furthermore, in the notes here: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~beresty/teach/StoCal/sc3.pdf I am having trouble surrounding defn 3.8 and the line before it on p. 39.  For the line before it, here is a seemingly legal cadlag adapted process which is necessarily previsible, but not locally bounded.  I take my favorite unbounded RV, and the process is constantly equal to that RV.  Same objection to the idea in defn 3.8 that $M^{{S'}_n}$ is $L^2$ bounded.  (I am mentally removing all the a.s..  Some of them are meaningful but seemingly unnecessary, but some of them are in the presence of no probability measure, such as the second one in defn 3.7)

Possibly being obscured by the problems before this point, I am having trouble making sense of equation (3.44).  The result of the integral is technically an equivalence class of indistinguishable processes.  So is he defining the whole process at once up to indistinguishability, and then recovering the slices for a fixed $t$ by evaluating into $L^2$ equivalence classes?

An answer to any subset of these is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your second objection.  If the process starts above your cutoff, wouldn't the stopped process be identically zero?  For your third question, everything here is done as equivalence classes in $L^2$ for the hidden random variable $\omega$, not $t$.

Comment: The most general answer to your first question that I know is called the Debut Theorem and the answer is yes.  I'm sure there is an easier proof if you only want to consider closed sets, but the link here is the easiest proof I've seen of the result in full generality: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3619v2.pdf

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian But it's not a cutoff as in like "truncation."  Rather it is a time-based cutoff.  So if I start out with the whole t=0 random variable above the cutoff, I don't get 0.  I get the first RV.  So taking the process to be, at all times, equal to a large RV, we can run into trouble.  I'm looking into the possibility that all my objections regarding finiteness are answered because he forgot to say that the processes start at 0.  But that still leaves the questions about well-definedness.  Regarding my 3rd question, it is the question of assembling...

Comment: many choices of equivalence class representatives together coherently into one cadlag process.  The cadlag part is particularly troubling.  Otherwise, I could just make a choice with axiom of choice.  It would be horrifying, and definitely not measurable in t and omega jointly.  But it would still be a noncadlag process.  Thanks for your reference on my first question.  I am surprised to find it is not trivial to answer my question, but of course happy if that is indeed the case in that I didn't overlook anything too easy.

Comment: If the process starts above the cutoff, then the set you are taking an indicator of is empty, right?
I'm still not sure what you mean in the third question.  What choice are you making with the axiom of choice?  Whenever you have $L^2$ processes on $[0,T]$ you can always do $L^2$ restrictions on $[0,t]$ for $t<T$.  If you are worried about the cadlag case, can I recommend using a text that handles it?  Berestycki's notes are good, but they only handle continuous processes.  Timo Seppalainen's notes may work for you: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/courses/735/notes.pdf

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Let's say that $X_0$ is cauchy distributed.  Then T may even be chosen to be $0$ everywhere (not in the context of the definitions, but to make a point here).  Even a cutoff like that isn't good enough because $[0, 0]$ still contains $0$.  But you are right, I did not entirely correctly conceive of how the cutoff worked.  The AC comment was regarding how one does not simply, for each $t$, pick a rep of the $L^2$ class.  Thanks for the notes.  It takes me a while to switch to someone else's perspective since I have to check everything again, although it gets easier and easier.

Comment: I'm also only interested in the cadlag case because its necessity was implied by the remark in between the two definitions in Nathanael's notes.  I was actually content even to follow Liggett's 2010 book which covers only the continuous case, with only a more specific class of integrators.  No mention of local martingales.  I like generality, but my motivation to get this general has only been as resources have suggested it.  That being said, your notes will definitely be useful as a reference.  Thanks.

Comment: The interval in the cutoff is $(0,T]$, not $[0,T]$ and alright, I misunderstood a bit what you were looking for wrt the cadlag stuff.  Good luck!

Comment: Ah you are right of course.  Originally I thought it was one of those min things (subconsciously of course).  But it's not stopped, nor truncated.  It is cut by the indicator.